# how to find the elements name in the xml file using DOM xerces c++..?

Tags: c++, xml-parsing, xerces, ixmldomelement

I want to know how to read all the elements' names in the following xml file:

```
<fruits>
    <apple> ... </apple>
    <banana> ... </banana>
    <grapes> ... </grapes>
    <mango> ... </mango>
    <papaya> ... </papaya>
    <strawberry> ... </strawberry>
</fruits>
```

Here, the condition is that I am not sure which fruits are available (e.g. whether or not apple is present on that day). I know only the element `<fruits>` is available; child names are unknown and the number of children for `<fruits>` is also unknown.

How can I find the fruits available on that day using Xerces DOM parsing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `DOMNodeIterator` to iterate all elements in your `DOMDocument` and then use the `DOMNode->getName()` to get the name and check if that's what you need.

Comment: DOMNode doesn't have getName() member function http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/apiDocs-3/classDOMNode.html